# Creating dynamic table and call c# method for dynamically created button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i have an issue in creating dynamic page. i need to create dynamic table,in that the table contains two text boxes and one button.i created and it displayed with help of string builder.

what i want is i need to write  C# code for dynamically created button.is it possible to append server button?when i click dynamically created button it should go to code behind.

```
sb.append("<input type='Button' runat='server'  onclick='Myfun()'");
```

Comment: Is this WebForms or MVC? Can you show the code for how you're rendering the layout so far?

Comment: it is of web form not mvc

Answer (score 3):

If it's asp.net webforms you can do this:

```
Button mybutton = new Button();
mybutton.Click += new EventHandler(Mybutton_Click);
container.Controls.Add(mybutton);
```

Make sure you add it to your OnInit method .

Comment: +1 Well done. I was writing something similar myself. It's worth mentioning that this code should be somewhere in `Page_Load` and should only be done if it's *not* a post back (i.e. `IsPostBack == false`).

Comment: i need to create with help of string builder ,,how can i write using string builder

Comment: @user1611125 You definitely don't need to be building controls using `StringBuilder` and raw HTML.  Follow the approach above.

Comment: for div it is possible to add like that and apply css also